# Link url of the jenkins build for the tag created in github

Tags: shell, jenkins, github

Im trying to add the build URL to the tag created in github.
Currently we are creating a tag automatically in the github repository when the build (jenkins) is executed.
We want to provide a link of the build url(jenkins) in the tag we create.
Can anyone help me with this functionality ?